# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: firebase

```
(base) Anupams-MacBook-Pro:Flash-Chat-iOS12-master anupamdeb$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing ChameleonFramework (2.1.0)
Installing Firebase (6.1.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /anaconda3/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/bv/xm2d3qyx6gl68vgzcks1zbp00000gn/T/d20190901-983-6r3zam/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/c7dba84b10c22663/Firebase-6.1.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect issue for anconda the good thing is  `conda deactivate`

and try again then it will works for you.